# How to code for an iOS style rotating animation

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, calendar, android-jetpack-compose

!(https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.ChQ6m89PO_1Dm_FexkwrUAAAAA?pid=ImgDet&dpr=2)
I would like to code this in Jetpack compose and have seen various other implementations already on stack overflow.
Please answer it in Jetpack Compose only.

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the code it seems you remove these slots intentionally:

```kotlin
    // Update the current time to be the end time of the chosen slot
    currentTime = chosenSlot.split("-")[1]
    currentMinutes = timeToMinutes(currentTime)
```

You can't choose slots at earlier time than already chosen slots. You can only go forward in time. Remove these lines of code to allow it.

But even then, I believe it won't work correctly. You add e.g. `21:00-22:00` to `booked`, but then you check e.g. for `21:00-21:30` and `21:30-22:00`, so you detect them as not booked. Instead, I suggest storing the info always in 30-minute slots and then when checking e.g. `21:00-22:30` you have to make sure all 3 required 30-minute slots are free.